# How to make smoke emission not be affected by force field?

Tags: smoke-simulation, force-fields

I'm trying to make a scene that contains two smoke flow sources inside the same domain. I want a force field to be added in the scene to affect the specific smoke but the other to be unaffected by it. 

 If possible, I want both the emitters to be in the same smoke domain. If I have to make separate domain for each of them, it will cost me for render time. So, any help will appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by having two domains, on different layers, each sharing its layer with its force field. 
I don't think that smoke particles within the same domain can be made to follow different rules based on where they're emitted from.

Comment: Do I need to manage the render layers as well?

Comment: A default render layer will render all visible layers, so it shoudn't require any extra work.